# How do I access XML attributes in PHP with simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hello, I have this piece of XML:

```
<foo id="whatever" default="whatever">
  FOO
</foo>
```

How can I access attributes like `id` or `default`?

If I `print_r($xml->foo)` I see them, but they are prepended with `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array syntax for attributes and object syntax for child nodes:

```
$xml->foo['id']  // get `id` attribute on `foo` node
```

See the `Using attributes` example here: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-4741

See also the [`attributes()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method.

Comment: but $node['id] gives me a object containing a array with that value, not the value :| Isn't there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: you can cheat and cast it to a string with `(string)$node['id']`